# OpenCV Android Continuous Mat width and height

Tags: android, opencv

I'm using the camera in the latest OpenCV 2.4.3 android project, and converting a Mat to a bitmap. The utility method I'm using (provided in the OpenCV project) requires a bitmap of the same width and height as the Mat to do the conversion. When I access the mat's height, it's 0. The width is 640 (as expected, I expected the height to be 480).

The Mat is continuous, and while I could understand this effecting mat.rows(), it shouldn't change the height?

For those asking for code: if you look at the Sample code, the camera activity has the following method:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);
    DoSomething(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
    return mRgba;
}
```

When I use the following to check the dimensions:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Width: " + mRgba.width() + ", Height:" + mRgba.height());
```

I get:

```
Width: 640, Height:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that when I call:

```
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
```

that indirectly calls this:

```
    mRgba.release();
```

which presumably changes the height to 0.